# Spring boot + JPA: ERROR 404 when creating data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

i tried to make a creating-data form. It was smoothy until today.    @RequestMapping("create")

```
 public String create() {
        return "backend/product/create";
    }
 
   
 @PostMapping(value = "create-form", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String createUserForm(ProductDto productDto, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                 HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        productService.saveProduct(productDto);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Tạo mới tài khoản " + productDto.getName() + " thành công!");
        return "redirect:/backend/product/create";
    }
```

this is when i click submit to save it to database.[image]

Anyone tell me why ?

Comment: I guess you do not have a mapping that answer this URL in your Spring MVC app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this will help you

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-url-encoded-form-data

```
@GetMapping("/backend/product/create")
public String create() {
    return "create page";
}
 
   
@PostMapping(value = "/create-form", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createUserForm(ProductDto productDto, 
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
    HttpServletResponse response, 
    HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        productService.saveProduct(productDto);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Tạo mới tài khoản " + productDto.getName() + " thành công!");
        return "redirect:/backend/product/create";
}
```